# UItable in a custom UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

I created a subclass of UIView CustomView. Also created a xib for that.
Added a tableView in xib and its delegate and datasource to File's owner.
Then added this view as follows.

```
nibViews = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomView"
                                             owner:self
                                           options:nil];
self.searchView = [ nibViews objectAtIndex: 0];
[self.view addSubview:self.searchView];
```

It crashes. Says `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]:unrecognized selector sent to instance.`
But I have implemented all datasource methods.

Then I removed datasource and delegate from xib to File's Owner.
Added following,

```
-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    self.table_userlist.delegate = self;
    self.table_userlist.dataSource = self;
    [self.table_userlist reloadData];

}
```

And now it works.

Please help me in understanding this scenario. What difference does it make when I set datasource, delegate from xib and programatically from `awakeFromNib`. 
Thanks.

Comment: In what method do you have that first block of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have implemented data source in the custom view and you are instantiating in the view in the view controller.

When you instantiate you take the owner ship of the view to view controller by saying `owner:self`. so the datasource has to be in view controller.

In awake from nib, the code is still in the view and you assign delegate view.

Comment: Thanks. Got it. I used this in viewController "nibViews = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CreateUserSearchView"
                                             owner:self
                                           options:nil];". So viewController became File owner. How can I make CustomView as owner?

Answer (score 0):

> and its delegate and datasource to File's owner

You must set these to your custom view instead of File's owner.
, and implement delegate and datasource methods in that view.